# Multiple (AND) queries for a nested index structure in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the below mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "xxxxx": {
      "properties": {
        "ID": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "pairs": {
          "type": "nested"
        },
        "xxxxx": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the `pairs` field is essentially an array of objects - each object has a unique ID associated with it

What i'm trying to do is to get only one object from the pairs field for updates. To that extent , i've tried this

```
GET /sample/_search/?size=1000
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "ID": "2rXdCf5OM9g1ebPNFdZNqW"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "pairs.id": "c1vNGnnQLuk"
              }
            }
          ]
      }
  },
  "_source": "pairs"
}
```

but this just returns an empty object despite them being valid IDs. If i remove the `pairs.id` rule - i get the entire array of objects .

What do i need to add/edit to ensure that i can query via both IDS (original and nested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `pairs` is of `nested` type, you need to use a [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html). Also you might probably want to leverage [nested `inner-hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) as well:

```
GET /sample/_search/?size=1000
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "ID": "2rXdCf5OM9g1ebPNFdZNqW"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "pairs",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "pairs.id": "c1vNGnnQLuk"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```

Comment: Thank you - but for some reason , i'm still getting the entire array of objects with the above query. do i need to refine it a bit more?

Comment: Check the `inner_hits` section in the response, you should only get the element that matches.

Comment: Oh you're right .. the inner_hits is returning the required object alone - thank you

Comment: What you can also do is to set `_source` to false if you don't need the `_source` section and you'll only get the inner hits.